# How can I allow Android to Doze while my app is open and the screen is on?

Tags: android, android-source, android-9.0-pie, android-doze, android-doze-and-standby

I am making an app that will run when the device is locked, via `Activity#setShowWhenLocked(true)`. I do not want to prevent the device from entering a low-power state. I know that the system does this with `Always-On Display`, and the display has an associated power mode for that:

[/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/Display.java](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/Display.java#294)

```
286    /**
287     * Display state: The display is dozing in a low power state; it is still
288     * on but is optimized for showing system-provided content while the
289     * device is non-interactive.
290     *
291     * @see #getState
292     * @see android.os.PowerManager#isInteractive
293     */
294    public static final int STATE_DOZE = ViewProtoEnums.DISPLAY_STATE_DOZE; // 3
295
296    /**
297     * Display state: The display is dozing in a suspended low power state; it is still
298     * on but the CPU is not updating it. This may be used in one of two ways: to show
299     * static system-provided content while the device is non-interactive, or to allow
300     * a "Sidekick" compute resource to update the display. For this reason, the
301     * CPU must not control the display in this mode.
302     *
303     * @see #getState
304     * @see android.os.PowerManager#isInteractive
305     */
306    public static final int STATE_DOZE_SUSPEND = ViewProtoEnums.DISPLAY_STATE_DOZE_SUSPEND; // 4
```

There is also this section in [/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/PowerManagerInternal.java](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/PowerManagerInternal.java):

```
51     * Wakefulness: The device is dozing.  It is almost asleep but is allowing a special
52     * low-power "doze" dream to run which keeps the display on but lets the application
53     * processor be suspended.  It can be awoken by a call to wakeUp() which ends the dream.
54     * The device fully goes to sleep if the dream cannot be started or ends on its own.
55     */
56    public static final int WAKEFULNESS_DOZING = 3;
```

If possible, I would like to **avoid using root** to do this, but if all else fails I could [manually control doze with root using these commands](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#testing_doze_and_app_standby), but that sounds messy and I don't want to mess up any other app's dozing interactions.

Also, I'm only particularly concerned with Android Pie (9.0) and later.

**Update:**

I have also tried acquiring a `DOZE_WAKE_LOCK`, but it requires the system permission `DEVICE_POWER`. I tried to `adb shell pm grant` the permission to my app, but it is not a changeable permission type.

Comment: What do you need your app to be doing? Playing content? Is there any background service going on or is it all about the user interface?

Comment: @YvetteColomb I want to display mostly static information (but maybe with a change or animation often enough to avoid burn-in)

Comment: @BLuFeNiX did you find any solution?

Comment: @user3405331 No, unfortunately. Though, I did my initial research on Android 9, so it is possible that Android 10 has some way to accomplish this.

Comment: @BLuFeNiX If we grant WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS permission through adb then we can edit device_idle_constants there must be some way out there but there is no proper documentation

Comment: @KhalidLakhani Interesting idea! I had not seen that settings key before. I just found this: https://github.com/easz/doze-tweak which does help shed some light on how to use the setting, including a diagram of the state transitions.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by [DreamService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/dreams/DreamService) which is a Screen Saver. You cannot do this by Activity. Activity prevent the device enter sleep mode.

> Dreams are interactive screensavers launched when a charging device is
>   idle, or docked in a desk dock. Dreams provide another modality for
>   apps to express themselves, tailored for an exhibition/lean-back
>   experience.

Comment: This will only work when the phone is plugged in or docked, unfortunately. I have looked at this strategy already, but could not find a reasonable way for the Dream to run while the phone was not charging or docked. I played around with using `adb shell dumpsys battery` to mock the battery state as charging, but this is not a realistic solution. Also, [Doze mode does not engage when the device is plugged into a power charger.](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/power/platform_mgmt#doze-life)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the ambient mode in android wear, which let an activity can show a drawable(usually some white lines with a black background) when device is slept. As far as I know, the code for phone device do not has this feature, because your activity must extends a class called WearableActivity and managed by an system app called Ambient. The wake lock `DOZE_WAKE_LOCK` you found is used in this Ambient app.